# how to find the barycentric coordinates of the orthocenter

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

$A = (0,0),B = (4,0),C = (1,2)$

How can I find the barycentric coordinates of the orthocenter of $\triangle ABC$?

Comment: [This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Altitude_(triangle)#The_orthocenter) may help.

Comment: It helped a lot, thanks!

Comment: @Daryl: Do you want to turn the essence of your comment into an answer, so we can get this out of the unsanswered queue?

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Altitude_%28triangle%29#The_orthocenter) Wikipedia page describes the orthocentre in barycentric coordinates of the triangle $ABC$ as
$$
\left((a^2+b^2-c^2)(a^2-b^2+c^2):(a^2+b^2-c^2)(-a^2+b^2+c^2):(a^2-b^2+c^2)(-a^2+b^2+c^2)\right),
$$ where $a=|BC|,b=|CA|$ and $c=|AB|$ are the side lengths of the triangle.

Comment: This is not the easiest expression. $(\tan(A),\tan(B),\tan(C))$ are simpler coordinates. See [this, table page 7](https://s3.amazonaws.com/aops-cdn.artofproblemsolving.com/resources/articles/bary.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

This is a more general method to find the orthocenterfor any given triangle ABC with: $A(x_A,y_A), B(x_B,y_B) \text{ and } C(x_C,y_C)$, and $H$ it's orthocenter. \

Let $A'$ the projection of $A$ on $BC$ 
$$
(AA') \perp (AC) \text{ and } \vec{AC} \begin{pmatrix}
x_C - x_A \\
y_C - y_A 
\end{pmatrix} \\
\implies (AA'):(x_C-x_B)(x-x_A)+(y_C-y_B)(y-y_A)
$$
For $B'$ the projection of $B$ on $AC$ ,and $C'$ the projection of $C$ on $BA$ we apply the same method.

Finaly: we found the system of equations for each altitude

$$
\begin{cases}
 (AA'):(x_C-x_B)(x-x_A)+(y_C-y_B)(y-y_A)\\
 (BB'):(x_C-x_A)(x-x_B)+(y_C-y_A)(y-y_B)\\
 (CC'):(x_B-x_A)(x-x_C)+(y_B-y_A)(y-y_C)
\end{cases} \\
\Longleftrightarrow \\
\begin{cases}
 (AA'):y=\frac{3}{2}x  \\
 (BB'):y=-\frac{1}{2} x+2 \\
 (CC'):x=1
\end{cases} \\
$$
We know that:
$$
\begin{cases}
 H \in (AA') \\
 H \in (BB')
\end{cases} \\
\implies \frac{3}{2}x_H = -\frac{1}{2}x_H+2 
\implies x_H = 1
$$
We substitute $x_H$ in the equation of $AA'$ to find $y_H$
$$
y_H = \frac{3}{2}
$$
The coordinates of the orthocenter $H$ is: $H(1,\frac{3}{2})$ 
Results are shown in the current figure
https://www.geogebra.org/calculator